# How to get Bash to find directories older than x days and delete them

Tags: bash, find

I have a backup folder with directories of mysql backup

**\backup**

- 2022-08-20
- ...
- 2022-09-12

I am running a crontab job to make the backups and then trying to delete the oldest directories, but keeping 14 of them.

This gives me all the directories modified in the last 14 days

```
find backup/ -type d -mtime +14
```

I had tried **exec rm()**

```
find backup/ -type d -mtime +14 -exec rm {}
```

This gives `rm: cannot remove ‘backup/2022-08-29’: Is a directory`

So I tried the **-delete** option

```
find backup/ -type d -mtime +14 -delete
```

But this gives this error `find : cannot delete 'backup/2022-08-29': Directory not empty`

**How can I do both at the same time ?**

Comment: Try: `find backup/ -type d -mtime +14 -exec rm -r {} +`. The problem is that you have non-empty directories, so, the command `rm` will fail. With `rm -r`  it removes the directories and their contents recursively.

Comment: I had tried **-r** before, but without the **+**.  All good now.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, with the line given by @EdgarMagallon